# CSS regression test on live data

Tags: html, css, testing, regression-testing

Is there any way to make reliable css regression test as integration test with live data?

For example: if i have a div with 'some short text' inside it, and then i'll change my css without breaking anything, *but* the data inside that div will change.

From my understanding the image will be different and the test will fail.

Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, can you elaborate or give an example?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to deal with failing css regression tests (with phantomCSS or any other tool) because of the data that changes the snapshots.